# Chrome native messaging, Error when communicating with the native messaging host

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to use Chrome extension native messaging feature. I had the C# program running, which will use standard output to write data. And in the chrome extension background.js file, chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener() was never fired. 
In the chrome extension page, I had following error:

```
  Unchecked runtime.lastError: Error when communicating with the native messaging host.
    Context_generated_background_page.html
    Stack Trace
    _generated_background_page.html:0 (anonymous function)
```

Following are the info about the testing project.

1. C# application. This method will be called once even triggered in the application.

   ```
   public static void Write(JToken data)
   {
       var json = new JObject();
       json["data"] = data;

       var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json.ToString(Formatting.None));
       /*
       foreach (var b in bytes)
           Console.WriteLine(b);
           */
       var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
       stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 0) & 0xFF));
       stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 8) & 0xFF));
       stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 16) & 0xFF));
       stdout.WriteByte((byte)((bytes.Length >> 24) & 0xFF));
       stdout.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
       stdout.Flush();
   }
   ```
2. background.js (update 1)

   ```
   var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('applistener');
   port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
     console.log("Received" + msg);
   });

   port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
     console.log("Disconnected");
   });
   ```
3. Chrome extension manifest file(manifest.json).

   ```
    "permissions": [ "nativeMessaging","activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
   ```
4. Native application manifest file.(almanifest.json)

   ```
   {
     "name": "applistener",
     "description": "Chrome native messaging test",
     "path": "C:\\Users\\xyz\\_test\\AppListener\\AppListener\\bin\\Release\\AppListener.exe",
     "type": "stdio",
     "allowed_origins": [ "chrome-extension://xxxxxmanextensionidxxxxxx/"]
   ```

   }
5. Create registry key.
   Followed the instruction from :https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-location

And I can see the key from Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\applistener

I am assuming when the event fired in the native app, in the chrome extension background.js, the listener event should be triggered. But I did not see that event triggered.

Update1: 
Change the code in background.js, using code sample from google documentation. port.onDisconnect.addListener() event fired, still get the error:

```
     Unchecked runtime.lastError: Error when communicating with the native messaging host.
```

I am trying to narrow down the issue at this point. I guess my registry key setting is correct? and write method in native app is the issue?

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the reply. I've tried modified the code in background.js. onDisconnect event fired, still error message though. I guess problem is the write method in native app?

Comment: I think all examples I've seen are sending a message from extension first, then the native app responds. I'm not that familiar with C# so I suggest you find and inspect an existing extension + native host in C#. I also think it might be possible to attach Visual Studio debugger to the running host process and debug it, otherwise you can write to a log file manually in order to "debug" the host.